# Cant scroll on div with overflow-y

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll

I have a short wrapper div with overflow auto (horizontal scroll). it contains a long div with inner divs. each inner div has a part inside with overflow-y scroll. when trying to scroll on that part especially when touching in mobile. you cant move on that part.

here is the code:

```
        <div class="wrapper">
            <section class="inner-wrapper col-xs-12 no-pad" id="photos">
                <% for (int i = 0; i < photos.Count; i++) { %>
                    <div class="no-pad timeline-images-inner" style="background: url(<%= photos[i].src %>); height:100%; width:100%; background-size: cover; background-position: center;">
                        <img src="<%= photos[i].src %>" class="timeline-images" alt="<%=photos[i].PhotoTitle %>">
                        <% if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(photos[i].PhotoTitle)){%>
                            <div class="image-desc text-right">
                                <div class="ixs"></div>
                                <div class="inner-photo-title">
                                    <%=photos[i].PhotoTitle%>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner-photo-desc change-en">
                                    <%=photos[i].LinkUrl%>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner-photo-text change-en">
                                    <%=photos[i].PhotoDescription %>
<%--                                    <div class="inner-photo-pic" style="background-image:url('<%=photos[i].src%>');">
                                    </div>--%>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <%} %>
                    </div>
                <% } %>
            </section>
        </div>
```

the problem is with inner-photo-text that has overflow-y:scroll.

you can see that problem on that site bottom. when you from narrow screen or from mobile.
http://michel.richkid.co.il/he/company/about/main/

thanks

Comment: set auto instead of scroll.